# Command in LWUIT

Tags: java-me, lwuit

How to add more than 2 command in a single row in at the Footer in lwuit Form ,suppose I want to add Back,Select,and Exit Command in a single row,how can I do that? Help with some example.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Display.getInstance().setThirdSoftButton(true);` for showing three softbutton's.

Answer (score 0):

You can also write `your_Form.setDefaultCommand(the_command_in_the_middle);`

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that setting commandBehaviour to SoftKey in the resource editor makes all your commands align on one side, typical blackberry behaviour, works on nokia also. It is a property of one of the constants of the theme in the resource editor.