# Lwuit Command Component

Tags: java-me, lwuit

T want to add more than 2 `Commands` in a single row in the Footer in `LWUIT` Form, suppose I want to add Back, Select and Exit Command in a single row. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this `Display.getInstance().setThirdSoftButton(true);`

See this [Command in LWUIT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7413429/command-in-lwuit)

Comment: True. I would also add that you can do whatever you want by overriding the MenuBar class or just placing components in the SOUTH section of a form.

Answer (score 0):

You can set Display.getInstance().setThirdSoftButton(true) in your midlet. The default lwuit list adds select by default on your list item so if you are using a lwuit list even adding select command is not required once you have enabled the thirdsoftkey.